# How do I resolve this error when starting ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

When run ruby bin/start I am getting this error. Can someone help me understand what to do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from bin/start:4:in `<main>'
        3: from bin/start:4:in `require_relative'
        2: from /Users/ivana/Desktop/online_projects/NYC Park CLI/lib/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
        22: from bin/start:4:in `<main>'
        21: from bin/start:4:in `require_relative'
        20: from /Users/ivana/Desktop/online_projects/NYC Park CLI/lib/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
        18: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
        17: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require'
        16: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
        15: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        14: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
        13: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/cli.rb:134:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `add_plugin_options'
        11: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `each'
        10: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib/pry/plugins.rb:55:in `load_cli_options'
         9: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         8: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
         7: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-byebug-3.7.0/lib/pry-byebug/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
         5: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
         4: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-byebug-3.7.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
         3: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
         2: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
         1: from /Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-byebug-3.7.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands/exit_all.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pry-byebug-3.7.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands/exit_all.rb:7:in `<module:PryByebug>': uninitialized constant Pry::Command::ExitAll (NameError)
```

Comment: Looks like either the ``pry`` or ``pry-byebug`` (or both) gems aren't installed in your environment. Try running ``gem info pry`` to ensure it's installed

Comment: its installed i get pry (0.13.1, 0.12.2, 0.11.3, 0.10.3)
pry-byebug (3.7.0) when run gem list

Comment: Does Ruby know how to find your GEMs? I.e. is your environment variable `GEM_HOME` set correctly?

Comment: If you use bundler, you also need to add `gem "pry"` to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle`. /Just installing the gem isn't enough, bundler has to also know about it.

Comment: @holgerJust yes i have gem pry in my Gemfile

Comment: @user1934428 not sure how to check that. This is my environment file:           
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pry'

require_relative './models/cli'
require_relative './models/scraper'
require_relative './models/park'

Answer (score 0):

Turn out, the issue likely stems from your usage of the slightly older [`pry-byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) 3.7.0 along with the newest [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) 0.13.1.

Unfortunately, in pry 0.13.0 there were some changes which require an update of pry-byebug to work with this version. According to the [Changelog of pry-byebug 3.9.0](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/releases/tag/v3.9.0), they added initial support for pry 0.13 in this version (and removed support for any older pry version).

Thus, to resolve this issue, you should either upgrade your pry-byebug version to 3.9.0 or downgrade your version of pry to something lower than 0.13. Depending on how  exactly you specified the dependencies in your `Gemfile`, it might be enough to just run the following command to upgrade your version of pry-byebug:

```
bundle upgrade
```